# why so many service events message triggered on uploading single file in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have Configured `S3` event notification and the `SQS` notification destination is used. I have ticked checkboxes event types as `Put`, `Post`,`Copy`,`Multipart upload` completed.For more details please check the attached screenshot.

For every single upload file, it is supposed to create single message but here I am getting more than one message. For the file that I have uploaded it is creating message like

```
{\"Records\":[{\"eventVersion\":\"2.0\",\"eventSource\":\"aws:s3\",\"awsRegion\":\"us-east-1\",\"eventTime\":\"2018-11-02T14:02:43.283Z\",\"eventName\":\"ObjectCreated:Put\",\"userIdentity\":{\"principalId\":\"AWS:AIDAIMIQPLFXDFSTWXCGM\"},\"requestParameters\":{\"sourceIPAddress\":\"10.4.50.122\"},\"responseElements\":{\"x-amz-request-id\":\"7EEC615C11B5C373\",\"x-amz-id-2\":\"GCI+e/xr+vKZjnCy3IpUJIn9XrIEzDdiZOTBKXzsqgbwqFDlZ91gGKWj8d0W/UbUdqoWYCuf1lw=\"},\"s3\":{\"s3SchemaVersion\":\"1.0\",\"configurationId\":\"InboundManifestSQSNotify\",\"bucket\":{\"name\":\"ftpayroll-test\",\"ownerIdentity\":{\"principalId\":\"A1JUPHJ1SEYN6S\"},\"arn\":\"arn:aws:s3:::ftpayroll-test\"},\"object\":{\"key\":\"inbound/PDL/Payslips/POL/TMF/MANIFEST_PS_POL_TMF_MS1_20180331_1.csv\",\"size\":4960,\"eTag\":\"df3a71421cc268356754c9069ca9d517\",\"sequencer\":\"005BDC59032AAAD3EE\"}}}]}\n" +
    " ";
```

along with this too many other messages also created which is of type as shown below
[image]

```
  {"Service":"Amazon S3","Event":"s3:TestEvent","Time":"2019-12-17T03:19:53.694Z","Bucket":"ftpayroll-test","RequestId":"3F75B2BB37BE2301","HostId":"60F12YlOkzRelFoiswS68VVmHJqwLS5A6zh7QBIqoZmBik7/HbyyDr/sdkpDaGxEBEbuYOLjilA="}
```

Comment: Only one event is created per action, with a unique `x-amz-request-id` and `sequencer` value. The `x-amz-request-id` is also in your bucket logs, and the `sequencer` values *for any one object key* tell you the precise order in which the events against that object key occurred.  If these values remain the same, you're seeing the same message, but if they change from message to message, then you are in fact performing multiple actions against the bucket, and the question is how/why?  What do the other messages contain?

Comment: Might it be a multi-part upload that is generating messages for each individual part (via PUT or POST)?

Answer (score 0):

s3 supports different API for putobject event. Like

- `s3:ObjectCreated:Post` – An object was created by HTTP POST operation.
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Copy` – An object was created an S3 copy operation.
- `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` – An object was created by
  the completion of a S3 multi-part upload.
- `s3:ObjectCreated:*` – An object was created by one of the event types
  listed above or by a similar object creation event added in the
  future.

Try `s3:ObjectCreated:*` event. Select **"All object created events"** from UI. Check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) for more details.

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked.